# Как через dd записать загрузчик MBR, потом через Live_USB, записать на раздел диска и править конфиг.файл Grub в Linux

Tags: linux, mbr

```
    Вопрос задал для ОС ядра Linux.
На компе установлено 2 ОС Manjaro последнего релиза , Debian 10, был установлен ранее
Смотрю на перёд - если вдруг система не будет загружаться!
Вот как я понял из видео лекций Специалист Linux 1-2 Сорокин Владимир.


ДЕЛАЕТСЯ ЗАРАНЕЕ ПЕРЕД УСТАНОВКОЙ ВТОРОЙ СИСТЕМЫ НА КОМПЬЮТЕР


Скопировать файл загрузчика(MBR) от Linux c диска /sda
размер загрузчика MBR равен 512 байт --- и в количестве 1

# dd if=/dev/sda of=mbr.bak bs=512 count=1

И в файловой системе Linux будет лежать файл mbr.bak


Или будет находится на флешке если запишем на неё

# dd if=/dev/sda of=/Путь_до_флешке/mbr.bak bs=512 count=1
```

*Можно ли сделать так для себя чтобы находилась запись на флешке????????*

***И вот в один из дней система не грузится !!!!!!!!!!!!***

```
Задача вернуть  mbr.bak в нулевой сектор
И руками поправить конфиг-файл загрузчика
Понадобится флешка с Live-образом (Ubunu, Debian, Mangaro, ...)записанным на неё
Стартуем с неё 
Заходим в терминал
Смотрим что у нас

sudo fdisk -l

Диск /dev/sda: 698,64 GiB, 750156374016 байт, 1465149168 секторов
......................
Устр-во    Загрузочный    начало      Конец    Секторы Размер Идентификатор Тип
/dev/sda1                   2048   12290047   12288000   5,9G            82 Linu
/dev/sda2               12290048  114690047  102400000  48,8G            83 Linu
/dev/sda3              114690048  217090047  102400000  48,8G            83 Linu
/dev/sda4              217090048 1465147391 1248057344 595,1G             5 Расш
/dev/sda5              217092096  524292095  307200000 146,5G            83 Linu
/dev/sda6              524294144  729094143  204800000  97,7G            83 Linu
/dev/sda8              790538240 1465147391  674609152 321,7G            83 Linu


Монтируем раздел sda в /mnt
# mount /dev/sda /mnt/ 
Подключаем флешку к компьютеру

подмонтируем  флешку  в точку монтирования /mnt

# mount /dev/sdb /mnt
# ls /mnt
```

> Или создать в /mnt/flash директорию flash и туда подмонтировать флешку ?????

```
Когда смонтируем то увидим в т.м. свой файл mbr.bak на флешке
```

> [[Наверное увидим файл mbr.bak если и не подключим флешку, но для этого
> он должен лежать в домашней директории записанный ]]???????????

```
Вернуть mbr.bak нужно так --- в первый сектор пишем
Если в домашней директории записанный лежит

Создадим директорию /mb в /mnt и туда скопируем файл mbr.bat

mkdir /mnt/mb

cp mbr.bat /mnt/mb

Оттуда запишем на /sda

# dd if=/mnt/mb/mbr.bak of=/dev/sda count=1
```

> или же так??????????

```
# dd if=/mnt/sdb/mbr.bak of=/dev/sda count=1

Уже выходным файлом будет if=/mnt/.../mbr.bak

А входным of=/dev/sda
```

> Далее наверное нужно **отмонтировать все** или же сперва **править** файл загрузчика ??????

```
# umount /dev/sda

# umount /dev/sdb
```

**А вот как править файл конфигурации Grub - что там прописать, где файл находится ?????**

*Подскажите **где у меня ошибки** - **если можно** то напишите **команды правильные***

**Вообще как нужно делать правильно!!!!!**

Comment: Почитал, увидел много низкоуровневой штуки. `grub-install` пробовал? Не помогло?

Comment: У вас gpt, mbr не несёт полезной информации.

Comment: don Rumata
Вы намекаете на то чтобы зайти с Live_USB потом из командной строки sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt а потом  sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda  потом я так понимаю сконфигурируется файл у Grub НО МНЕ ИНТЕРЕСНО а что я прописывал можно так --- но не знаю правильно ли и кто нибудь показал бы реальный код

Comment: 0andriy
 А как понять что mbr.bak не несёт полезной информации.Он ведь скачан с только что установленной системы - там таблица и загрузчик и всё 512 байт, что надо понимать что только система при установки сама установит с правильными байтами - а в скачанном файле нет полезной информации и он не пригоден для восстановления.

Comment: Может я вообще не так понимаю.

Comment: Может я вообще не так понимаю. Вот у меня не грузится система  - допустим ,В чём причина - первое наверное Grub "полетел" значит нужно переустановить Grub , но тогда причём MBR со своим загрузчиком в 466 байт и таблицей разделов в 46 байт они должны быть целыми.Загрузчик в 466 байт работает по запросу BIOS загружает ему таблицу разделов в 46 байт --- так я понял если это правильно.Загрузчик Grub и  MBR-загрузчик --- это ведь разные загрузчики или я ошибаюсь.